# Vue + Inertia added to Laravel 10, now I am getting 'autocomplete not a function' when loading a Vue component

Tags: jquery, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-10

**CONTEXT:** I have an established and mature Laravel application built entirely with Laravel, Blade, Javascript and JQuery. When I load a blade view from the Laravel portion of the site I get no errors in my chrome dev tools. NOTE: I use Mix, and there are no MIX warnings. I wanted to get away from JQuery, and so I want to add Inertia + Vue for *future* front end Blade views and later, progressively removing the JQuery. I know this works fine as I have already done this on a much smaller application.

**PROBLEM DEFINED:** I have successfully loaded Vue+Inertia and my simple "Hello World" component displays well. However, my problem is that the existing mature application uses the JQuery function "autocomplete" in several places. For some reason when I load my Vue component my Chrome dev tools are filled with the error below. All I want is to be able to run Vue + Inertia inside my mature app without these errors:

```
jquery.js:4059 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

NOTE: All the bade views with autocomplete belong to the Laravel side of the app do not give any dev tools errors.

I have spent the last 2 days searching through everything I can find on the web. No one on Laracasts knows the solution, and don't get me talking about "AI".

Answer (score 0):

The error you’re seeing, $(...).autocomplete is not a function, suggests that the jQuery UI library (which provides the autocomplete function) is either not being loaded, or is being loaded in the wrong order. Where/When do you load jQuery?

Comment: The problem has been solved thank you. It all had to do with the configuration of Laravel MIx